# An algebra with no von Neumann unitization

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

What is an example of a non unital $C^*$ algebra which can not be an essential ideal of any von Neumann algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe $C_0(\mathbb R)$ is  an example.

If $C_0(\mathbb R)$ is an essential ideal in some unital algebra $A$,  then
$A$ embedds in the multiplier algebra of $C_0(\mathbb R)$,  so $A$ must be commutative.

The spectrum of $A$ will then
be a compact space containing an open dense copy of $\mathbb R$.   Since the closure of a connected set is connected,  we see that the spectrum of $A$ is connected.

This implies that $A$ has no nontrivial projections
so it cannot be a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your answer